# Navigation using react-navigation v2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Let's make it simple.

I've 3 screens. `Splash`, `Home` and `Settings`. I am using [ReactNavigation-v2](https://reactnavigation.org/)'s `StackNavigator` for navigating between screens. The program flow is as follows, `Splash -> Home -> Settings`. Everything works fine except one thing. When i press back button from Home, I am getting the `Splash` screen from stack.

So the question is, How do i delete the `Splash` screen from navigator stack and prevent from going back to `Home -> Splash`.

I've googled alot and couldn't find a perfect solution. I know there are many 3rd party libraries out there, but i want to use ReactNavigation.

If you need more details, ask me in the comments.

NOTE: I am new in react-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with 2 options.

First option is to [reset navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset) stack when you navigate from `SplashScreen` to Home screen.

> The `Reset` action wipes the whole navigation state and replaces it with
>   the result of several actions.

**Sample**

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Second option is to use [`SwitchNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) in combination with `StackNavigator`.

> The purpose of `SwitchNavigator` is to only ever show one screen at a
>   time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes
>   to their default state when you switch away. This is the exact
>   behavior that we want from the authentication flow.

Comment: Perfect. tnx @bennygenel